# How to close hibernate session after transaction boundary

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, jta

We are trying to upgrade from Spring3/Hibernate3 to Spring4/Hibenate4. One of the issues we are seeing is that with Hibernate3, when the entities are fetched from the service layer with transaction boundaries around the service methods, the entities didn't have an active open session for lazily loaded properties. The transaction manager used to call **SpringSessionSynchronization**'s afterCompletion that unsets all sessions.

Now with spring4+hibernate4 combo, we are seeing that the entities come back with active open sessions on them. The transaction manager is now calling **SpringFlushSynchronization** instead of SpringSessionSynchronization which does not do anything after a commit is performed. So what happens now is that when the entities with the old session gets passed to another service call with a separate transaction boundary, it is met by the error:

```
Illegal attempt to associate a collection with two open sessions
```

Note that the transaction manager is using JTA in my case if that is relevant. Is there some change in the way Spring now works that is producing this change in behaviour - and is there a remedy to address the issue?

Comment: Which version bitronix you use? Have problems with bitronix/sprng/hibernate4/5?

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I had not set the JTATransactionFactory. Adding this to the hibernate configuration resolved my issue:

```
            <prop key="hibernate.current_session_context_class">jta</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform">org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.BitronixJtaPlatform</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JTATransactionFactory</prop>
```